# Is there a way to exclude certain apps from the chooser dialog?

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm using the following code to let the user select a photo from their device. This is pretty standard and will display the typical chooser dialog showing a list of possible applications that can handle this event.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), Constants.PICK_PHOTO);
```

I want to exclude Picasa from this list. Is there a way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to exclude *Picasa*?

Comment: Basically because Picasa handles image URIs in a different way then the normal image chooser and I wanted to know if there a quick, 2 minute fix for now before actually implementing the code for this edge case.

Comment: If someone has Picasa installed and it shows up for every app except yours, users will think it's a bug (unless you explain it, but why should they care about URI formats?).

Comment: You basically need to handle this differently. The issue is explained here (there's also a solution here, but I just wanted to know it this was possible in Android): http://dimitar.me/how-to-get-picasa-images-using-the-image-picker-on-android-devices-running-any-os-version/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`PackageManager.queryIntentActivities`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#queryIntentActivities%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) to determine which apps can handle the intent, then create a custom chooser dialog. For more details related to how to do this, see [Custom filtering of intent chooser based on installed Android package name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5734678/custom-filtering-of-intent-chooser-based-on-installed-android-package-name) and [Custom ListView in a dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18799764/custom-listview-in-a-dialog).

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't remove any apps from this list. You can only ask a user to choose your app (for example before the list is displayed).